# Java - SimpleDateFormat string to Date to mills conversion

Tags: java, date

I have been given a reason to fiddle around in JAVA standard API and my oh my do I detest dates in it.
So my problem is with time unit conversion. Now as an input I get a string say: "19.1", "33.79", "10.321" or "10.23.66"...

So one would expect "mm.ss.SS", "ss.SS", "ss.SSS" patterns and with a magic of SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ss.SS");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(getTimeZone("GMT"));
dateFormat.parse("19.1").getTime();
```

But the result is somewhat strange. I hope to get 19100 mills although I get 19001L mills. Is this right conversion ?

Also this does not ensure that "19,1111" will be 19011L or that it will not match "ss.SS" pattern and I will get an exception. With all SimpleDateFormat might this will successfully parse into 20111L in mills. I really am confused on this...  does it suppose to work like that?

Comment: I think if you want `19100` millis, you need to provide a value of `19.100`.  Basically you're asking for `19.001`...

Comment: Take a look at your number, you are passing in `19.1`, you are then parsing is `ss.SS`. So `ss=19` and `SS=1 != 100`, i.e. trailing zeros and leading zeros are **not** the same thing. This is decimal arithmetic after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to work like that, and I am afraid you'll have to parse this format for yourself. That shouldn't be all that hard though...

```
long millis = 0;
String[] numbers = dateString.split(".");
millis += Integer.parseInt(numbers[numbers.length-1]) * 
          (int)Math.pow(10,numbers[numbers.length-1].length()-3));
for (int i=2; i<=numbers.length; i++) {
  millis += Integer.parseInt(numbers[numbers.length-i]) *
            (int)Math.pow(60,i-1) * 100;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should provide you with an adequate starting point.